# Jquery is not working inside a twig template

Tags: jquery, html, twig

Im using twig template manager to render a page that shows a bootstrap tab navigation, I have proven with many codes but no one seem to work, and is not working because seeing the inspector apparently links are not grabing the jquery events, I have tried all the codes in a simple html page and work perfectly , this is the last thing I probe ( w3school example):

```
{% block tabs %}

    <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs with jQuery</h2>

    <p>Click on the Tabs to display the active and previous tab.</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="first" class="tab-pane fade in active">
             <h3>HOME</h3>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
         </div>
         <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
             <h3>Menu 1</h3>
             <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
         </div>
         <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
             <h3>Menu 2</h3>
             <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
         </div>
         <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
             <h3>Menu 3</h3>
             <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
    <hr>
    <p class="act"><b>Active Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
    <p class="prev"><b>Previous Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
   </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
        $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
            var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
            var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
            console.log(x);
            console.log('y');

            $(".act span").text(x);
            $(".prev span").text(y);
        });
    });
    </script>

{% endblock tabs %}
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: if you could provide a link to this example, it would be easier to find the bug

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Are you loading this html using ajax?

Comment: Here is the example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab_events2&stacked=h

Comment: The console is giving me this Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, can that be the problem?

Comment: Of course it can... sounds like you didn't include jQuery.js in the page or your code is being loaded before jQuery.js

Comment: Yep thats the problem, but Im calling this template from another with the jquery import and twig for some reason is not loading jquery, importing jquery again inside the template fix the problem, thanks!